# Build android apk with buildozer

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I almost tried every tutorial I could find online about building an apk from python, I cant make it.
First setup:
Lubuntu on Eee pc 901 (on a 32gb sd card with 2gb ram- not a live cd -running alongside with windows 10)
I have setup all the prerequisities and I am trying to build a simple hello world app.
I have run into various errors
"Aidl is missing..."
or "command failed: ./distribute.sh -l"

1st question. 
Is it possible to do it in this setup or am I wasting my time (not taking into account the slow cpu of the netbook).

Second setup
the prebuilt VM from [here](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android-vm.html#kivy-android-vm) and I also get the above "command failed" error.

2nd question
Where (which folder) do I run the buildozer android debug command.
In the same folder with the main.app? in the root? how?

I am a complete noob in linux so please be very descriptive.

Comment: Looks like the eee pc 901 has an atom processor. I wonder if that causes any problems. But regardless, post the full output from these commands (including the errors) if you want help solving them.

Comment: I did a clean install (Lubuntu) in my eee pc and followed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23024248) instructions. 
These [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B2rCEv1yeAl0S3NyTDFIaWlDSkE&usp=sharing) are my buildozer.spec, main.app and output of buldozer android debug (>log.txt).
Can you figure out where is the mistake?

Comment: Your log seems to have lost its newlines. Can you fix that?

Comment: How? I run "buildozer android debug >log.txt"

Answer (score 3):

You actually don't need a sdk manager as buildozer will download that itself.
For a clean install try

```
buildozer -v android clean
```

after deleting .buildozer folder from your /home/ and then try

```
buildozer -v android debug
```

Also set the log level as 2 in buildozer.spec and if you are using any python library add that in buildozer.spec requirement section with comma after kivy.For example if you are using numpy include that in following way

```
requirements = kivy,numpy
```

Let me know if these fix work.

Answer (score -1):

My environment is
Eee pc 901 netbook with Lubuntu 15.10
Python 2.7.10
Buildozer 0.30
Kivy 1.9.0
cython 0.21.2
In SDK manager I have installed the following:
Tools -->

- Android SDK Tools 24.4.1
- Android SDK Platform-tools 23.1
- Android SDK Build-tools 20, 23.0.1 and 23.0.2

Android 4.4.2 (API19) -->

- SDK Platform
  Extras -->
- Android support library

After millions of attempts to build an apk with buildozer I got various errors (Aidl not found...,  Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy"... etc)
I finnaly managed to do it with the above configuration.
For the Aidl error I think the problem was an uninstalled "thingy" in the SDK
For the command failed error the problem was in the cython version. Check (http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html) to see which version of cython works for each version of Kivy (under Installation in a Virtual Environment --> Common dependencies --> Cython)﻿