# Buildozer Build failed: Couldn't find executable for CC

Tags: python, android, linux, kivy, buildozer

I run the command --buildozer android debug , because i wan to create a apk file to my phone,but after i reach this point

```
[INFO]:    Building libffi for armeabi-v7a
**[ERROR]:   Build failed: Couldn't find executable for CC.** This indicates a problem locating the /home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-armv7l/bin/clang executable in the Android NDK, not that you don't have a normal compiler installed. Exiting.
Searching path are: '/home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-armv7l/bin:/home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/:/home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/:/home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b:/home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk/tools:/home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/bin/jdk-10/bin:/path/to/inflated/jdk-10/bin:/path/to/inflated/jdk-10/bin:/path/to/inflated/jdk-10/bin:/path/to/inflated/jdk-10/bin:/home/pi/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games'
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/pi/Downloads/kivy/MySecApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'lxde-pi-'
#     _LXSESSION_PID = '693'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/tmp/ssh-jWSrVLoiseSQ/agent.693'
#     XDG_CONFIG_HOME = '/home/pi/.config'
#     JAVA_OPTS = '-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'LXDE-pi'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '747'
#     NO_AT_BRIDGE = '1'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     PWD = '/home/pi/Downloads/kivy/MySecApp'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'lightdm-xsession'
#     LOGNAME = 'pi'
#     QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME = 'qt5ct'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/pi/.Xauthority'
#     XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/lightdm/data/pi'
#     HOME = '/home/pi'
#     LANG = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'LXDE'
#     VTE_VERSION = '5402'
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     USER = 'pi'
#     DISPLAY = ':0.0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     XDG_VTNR = '7'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = 'c2'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/local/share:/usr/share/raspi-ui-overrides:/usr/share:/usr/share/gdm:/var/lib/menu-xdg'
#     PATH = '/home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/bin/jdk-10/bin:/path/to/inflated/jdk-10/bin:/path/to/inflated/jdk-10/bin:/path/to/inflated/jdk-10/bin:/path/to/inflated/jdk-10/bin:/home/pi/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games'
#     GDMSESSION = 'lightdm-xsession'
#     SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN = 'gtk3'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/pi'
#     TEXTDOMAIN = 'Linux-PAM'
#     _ = '/home/pi/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/pi/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

It showing this **Build failed: Couldn't find executable for CC.** error . 
Why seems to be the problem here?
Any help will be appreciated , thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I spent a lot of time on buildozer and this error also. In my case Python-for-Android made wrong path to clang (that CC executable).

Here we have

```
'/home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-armv7l/bin
```

So check if the folder's name in '/home/pi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/ is really 'linux-armv7l'. If it's not just go to your python-for-android folder and there /pythonforandroid/util.py

Open it and find there 'build_platform' variable and after that you can just comment code that is going after '=' sign, and write there your real folder's name as a string. For example:

```
build_platform = 'linux-x86_64'
```

It helped me, maybe it will help you.

Comment: I now have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64468814/buildozer-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables) error.